# Jquery get class name and store as variable

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a variable that grabs a class name from a link that exists. Then Im trying to add that variable to another element.

https://gist.github.com/788460

Comment: What results are you expecting, and what results are you expecting?

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson, i think you mean: "and what results are you experiencing?"

Comment: what does your HTML look like?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/788460

Answer (score 1):

Your variable definition is scoped inside the click event's function.  Do this instead:

```
var $myClass, $filterAlpha, $filterBeta;

$("ul ul li a").click(function() {
    $myClass = $(this).attr("class");
});

$filterAlpha = $('#alpha ul li a').addClass($myClass);
$filterBeta =  $('#beta ul li a').addClass($myClass);
```

Comment: Stephen, Thanks so much for the quick response. Giving this a try right now.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I've updated this: https://gist.github.com/788460

I'm trying to get my var filterAlpha to alert me of the class of the link I click on, but it doesn't seem to be adding that class.

Comment: Updated the gist again: https://gist.github.com/788460 with the html this time. Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't work because `$myClass` is `null`. The binding of the event is happening at the same time that you're calling `addClass()`